# docusign rest api create an enveloppe in complete status

Tags: docusignapi

We would like to archieve documents which don't have to be signed on docusign, is there a possibility to create an enveloppe as complete (skipping the signing part) in order to be able to directly create working view links ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could send an envelope with just one cc recipient. That cc recipient could be a blackhole email address on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send and complete an envelope w/o recipients.  A CarbonCopy will create and send and complete the envelope, but what do you mean by create working view links?

If you are referring to using the API to pull the completed documents then yes this is possible.

Comment: I finally gave up exporting documents without tab, tried the carbon copy technique but was not properly working whether because the document status keep been 'sent' and i couldn't embed a view link from my app https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createViewLink/ (doc should be complete), or wether because the api refused a doc without tab i don't recall exactly. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why can't you just get the document PDF and render in your app?  

{{baseurl}}/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/combined